# Display message on the top of current jsp page with blur background while redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

We've `click here` button (which takes the user to another site)  once user clicks on that button, a message needs to be displayed to the user `you are now redirecting to the site2`.

We require the message to be displayed with blur background of the current page (user do not allowed to do any other operation while displaying this message)

After two seconds, user should be redirected to the new page in new window.

How can I achieve this one in `JavaScript`? And `JSP/html` page.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_filter_blur for how to blur the thing.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? If yes can you show what you tried and what you already have?

Comment: once user clicks on the button, i am trying to display alert message by using alert method in java script, but i dont want to take the input from the user, just i need to display the message "you are redirecting to site" after 2 or 5 second the new site should need to open in new tab.

Comment: Please post your code of what you've done by yourself.

Comment: <a href="javascript;redirect()">click her</a> and in java script <script type ="text/java script"> function redirect(){ alert("you are now redirecting to new site"); window.open ("http://URL");  in this case user need to press on ok button in alert window , but i dont want to take input from user it just need to display message and after 5 secons need to redirect to new URL,